# C# threading parallel

Tags: c#

Help is very welcome and extremely appreciated, thank you. What this program is, is a ProxyChecker, because i've bought a bunch and will continue to do so of proxies with different user/passes etc, however some have expired. I added a break point and what it's doing is actually skipping the ProxyClient code and going straight to for each var item in 1, if item accepts connection etc, it then just returns false and finishes.

```
private static void CheckProxy(object state)
{
    var u = user[0];
    var p = pass[0];
    var l = new List<MyIP>();
    Parallel.ForEach(l.ToArray(), (ip_item) =>
    {
        try
        {
            string ip = ip_item.IP;
            using (var client = new ProxyClient(ip, u, p))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ip, user, pass);
                client.Connect();
                ip_item.AcceptsConnection = client.IsConnected;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            l.Remove(ip_item);
        }
    });
    foreach (var item in l)
    {
        if (item.AcceptsConnection == true)
        {
            WriteToFile(user[0], pass[0]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(item.IP + " is " + (item.AcceptsConnection) + " accepts connections" + " doesn not accept connections");
    }
}
```

Load ips function:#

```
private static void loadips()
        {
            using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader("ips.txt"))
            {
                var l = new List<MyIP>();
                string line = null;
                while ((line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    l.Add(new MyIP { IP = line });
                }
            }
        }
```

I have added this in response to the answer. I believe this is a variable issue as the variable is locally declared not publicly any ideas how to fix? i'm unable to find a way to get this working seems like i'm being dumb. thanks.

Comment: You never call loadips()

Answer (score 0):

Your code "skips" the `Parallel.ForEach` because the *local* variable `l` is an **empty** list (you just created it with `new List<MyIP>()`.

Your `loadips()` method only fills a list referenced only by (another) **local** variable `l`, which is out of scope when the `using` block is left.

There are several ways to solve that. If both methods are in the same class, you could declare a *member* variable in that class of type `List<MyIP>` and fill that list in your `loadips()`.

My suggestion would be to change `loadips()` so that it *returns* the list of read ip addresses and call this from `CheckProxy()`:

```
private static List<MyIP> loadips() // changed return type to List<MyIP>
{
    using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader("ips.txt"))
    {
        var l = new List<MyIP>();
        string line = null;
        while ((line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            l.Add(new MyIP { IP = line });
        }
        return l; // return the list!
    }
}
```

and the `CheckProxy`:

```
private static void CheckProxy(object state)
{
    var u = user[0];
    var p = pass[0];
    var l = loadips(); // load IPs here
    Parallel.ForEach(l.ToArray(), (ip_item) =>
    { 
        ...
```

Comment: Hi, is there away to put more parameters in to the for each statement? i.e. Parallel.ForEach(l.ToArray(), (ip_item) && (l2.ToArray(), (userpass_item) =>?